# Prerequisites for using C# 6 Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

There's a lot of buzz around C# 6

However, I wanted to know that if they work in asp.net and asp.net mvc?

I mean, C# 6 cannot just run in framework 4.5 (*Or can it?*)

Should we use C# 6 for backend of asp.net/(mvc), because mostly all doesn't have private servers.

So, should we wait for hosters like godaddy to upgrade their system, before we could use much anticipated c# 6?

Comment: Why? The compiler emits bytecode, the runtime runs bytecode. Why would you think a new compiler version would change the bytecode that the runtime can handle?

Comment: @leppie, so according to you, I should be able to use c# without any extra requirements for the backend of my website?

Comment: We have in the past added language features that demanded a new runtime (think generics, or interface covariance.) So far, C# 6.0 has not done this.

Answer (score 2):

The preview-release of the C# 6.0 compiler is just that - a compiler. It doesn't target a new version of the .NET Framework. As such, there's nothing new that needs to be installed on your server - you just compile your code with the new compiler, upload it, and you're done.

Of course, this doesn't mean that all features will be available if you're not using a sufficiently up-to-date version of .NET - if you're targeting .NET 2.0, obviously you don't get to use LINQ since that was introduced in .NET 3.5.

Also, a lot of the features you've heard "buzz" about haven't even been implemented yet, even in the preview-release. They're *planned*, that's all. If there's a particular feature you've heard about that you're wanting to make use of, you should check whether it's even been implemented before you even bother downloading it.

The point though is that the C# compiler and the .NET framework are two completely separate things. There has not (yet) been any announcement of a new version of the .NET framework.

Another point worth bearing in mind though is that the preview-release compiler is exactly what it says - a preview-release. This is NOT the final release, and you need to be aware that features could change or even be removed from under you by the time the final release comes around. How likely that is, I can't say, and the risks involved in using new features introduced with a preview compiler for a production application are for you to weigh.